# PyTorch: copy_if failed to synchronize: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: copy_if failed to synchronize: device-side assert triggered

when trying to execute:

`if torch.nonzero(gt_class_ids > n_classes).size()[0] > 0:`

where `gt_class_ids` is `Torch.cuda.LongTensor` of size [128] and `n_classes` = 81.
Running on cuda 9.x

Answer (score 4):

The following code works for me.

```
n_classes = 81
gt_class_ids = torch.from_numpy(numpy.random.randint(1, 100, size=128)).long()

if torch.nonzero(gt_class_ids > n_classes).size(0) > 0:
    print('okay')
```

One suggestion: run the code without using cuda and then you will be able to see the real error message. Sometimes when we run code using cuda, it gives error message having `device-side assert triggered` which hides the real error message.

Comment: Strongly second the suggestion of checking on CPU, IMO these errors are often due to some indexing error.

Comment: To better understand what the real error is you can also run with the flag

`CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1` and sometimes this helps